# Jquery - greater than usage not working in IE / safari

Tags: jquery

I'm experiencing an issue with a function not executing  through an if statement in IE and Safari.  My code is working in chrome and firefox.  In a product list view I'm picking up each product by the product name.  I'm then determining its length and height and if its creating a multi line name in its container I want to push the product down to line up the product names.

For some reason in IE and Safari the function won't execute past this if statement.

```
if( ( currNameLength >= 39 ) && ( currNameHeight >= 36 ) ) {
```

it executes if I use =, so I believe IE and Safari don't like the >=

```
    $('.name-link').each(function() {

    var currNameLength = $(this).text().length;
    var currNameHeight = $(this).height(); 
    var currName = $.trim($(this).text());

    if( ( currNameLength >= 39 ) && ( currNameHeight >= 36 ) ) {

        $(this).parents('div[class="product-tile"]').css('position', 'relative');
        $(this).parents('div[class="product-tile"]').css('top', '20px');
        $(this).parents('div[class="product-tile"]').css('border', '1px solid green');

    }

});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check `console.log(currNameHeight)` if it's working ?

Comment: I have had issues in the past with IE treating a number as a string, even though it was clearly assigned as a number. My workaround was to call parseInt on it every time.

Comment: Not sure why you need currNameLength >= 39 if you already have currNameHeight >= 36 ?

Comment: @DinoMyte, currNameHeight might be greater than 36 while currNameLength might be smaller than 39. They are different variables...

Comment: Never mind. Didn't notice they are 2 diff variables.Sorry

Comment: console.log(currNameHeight);  ouputs a number to the console

Answer (score 2):

This is because the value is returned as String. Try to add:

```
  parseInt(currNameHeight)
```

When you use greater than, the engine is expecting a number. then when it sees a string it breaks.

parseInt() will parse strings into integers

Also, since the value might be returned with 'px' at the end of it do this:

```
 //to remove the px from the value before parsing it
 parseInt(currNameHeight.replace('px',''))
```

currNameHeight.replace('px','') will replace any 'px' it finds in the string with 'nothing' before parsing it as a number.